# chip45 bootloader in Atmega32U4

Tags: avr, bootloader

Good morning. I am using the chip45 bootloader for an Atmega chip.
The chip being used is the Atmega32U4 chip ("chip45boot2_atmega32u4_uart1_v2.9Q").

I am having a strange error. I burn the bootloader with a success message from the AVR ISP.
Then when I use the chip45 GUI it says no bootloader.
Then I decide to see if there is anything written in my flash. I do a read of the flash.
I see an anomaly. Almost everything is written except the last couple of lines. I think this is causing the 
error message I am pasting the actual boot and the read boot below.

Actual boot -

**:107EE0000801811102C08BE201C08DE20E94463C74
:107EF000BCCDF999FECF92BD81BDF89A992780B586
:107F00000895DC01CB0103C02D910E948C3F4150AC
:107F10005040D0F70895262FF999FECF1FBA92BD91
:107F200081BD20BD0FB6F894FA9AF99A0FBE01965A
:027F30000895B2
:040000030000780081
:00000001FF**

Read boot -

**:107EE0000801811102C08BE201C08DE20E94463C74
:107EF000BCCDF999FECF92BD81BDF89A992780B586
:107F00000895DC01CB0103C02D910E948C3F4150AC
:107F10005040D0F70895262FF999FECF1FBA92BD91
:107F200081BD20BD0FB6F894FA9AF99A0FBE01965A
:107F30000895FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFB2
:107F4000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF41
:107F5000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF31
:107F6000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF21
:107F7000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF11
:107F8000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF01
:107F9000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF1
:107FA000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE1
:107FB000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD1
:107FC000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC1
:107FD000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFB1
:107FE000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA1
:107FF000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF91
:00000001FF**

Sir, as you can see from above, after the line (":107F200081BD20BD0FB6F894FA9AF99A0FBE01965A") there is some confusion.
Have any of you encountered such an issue before. 
I then tried checking if anything is wrong with the clock and such. I am able to program
the chip and also toggle a pin using the AVR studio.

I know its a very narrow doubt which I should ask chip45 directly, but in case anyone can help me it would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dump you have shown is identical to the original hex in all the parts that matter. The boot code finishes at byte address 7F30. Subsequent lines of the dump that are filled with FF are just showing blank bytes in the flash memory.

The couple of lines at the end of the original hex file which are different are not part of the actual boot code. The second to last line is [Intel Hex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX) record type 03, which sets the segment address to 7800 (starting address of the boot code). The last line simply marks the end of the file.

Your problem must be due to something else. Perhaps your fuse settings are wrong, or you have a wiring error, or it's the wrong bootloader for your setup.